# How to do alter INDEX detach partition or alternatives in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Given a table with index and partitioning it.

One can do `create index parent_idx on only parent using (id)`

And then later `alter index parent_idx attach partition child_idx`

The advatage is that long operation of creating `child_idx` is skipped

But then how does one remove index from one child table, and keep it on others?

The advantage would be not recreating indexes on child tables, because when parent index is dropped, it is dropping all child indexes.